# writing research proposal for extending work

Tags: research-proposal

Many suggestions are focused on the original idea of the research proposal, for which it should be unique, for it to get accepted. However, little or no suggestion at all to write a research proposal to extend the work based on some well-setup idea/work. That in fact has more chance to be successful, if the original idea has been proved and well developed. So why it is not promoted when submitting the research proposal? Any successful work is always based on some previous great ones. How many have set it up as a ground breaking and standalone one? few, right?

Answer (score 1):

What's an "idea"? Isn't it also an "idea" to come up with cases where an existing technique fails, and to extend the original technique for those cases? Like you say, "[a]ny successful work is always based on some previous great ones." There is simply no difference between building on existing stuff and having that one great idea -- the one great idea is also building on stuff 99% of the time. It's all just a matter of how you explain things.